# Modal de bootstrap no abre en react

Tags: bootstrap, reactjs, modal

No se por que al pulsar sobre el botón, el modal de bootstrap no se abre.

En mi index.js tengo importado el css

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

He comprobado que el módulo existe en node_modules/bootstrap....
He comprobado en package.json que existe `"bootstrap": "^4.3.1"` en dependencias 
No recibo ningún error, cuando le pulso a botón no se abre el modal.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Pruebas extends Component {


render() {
  return (

<div>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
    </button>


    <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-header">
            <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-body">
            ...
        </div>
        <div className="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pruebas;
```

Comment: Hola Lorenzo, revisando en ediciones veo que cambiaste por completo el sentido de la pregunta, si encontraste una posible solución, te aconsejo la publiques como una respuesta o bien como una actualización.

Comment: no se muy bién como podría publicarlo como una actualización? Me podría indicar?

Comment: Puedes ver información relacionada en estos enlaces: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/editing - https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Fijate bien el `exampleModal`, los id que conicidan los textos!